# Determine signal quality or signal strength through hostapd or iw

Tags: wifi, hostapd

I would need to retrieve the signal strength through hostapd or iw of my Access Point (AP) device which I am using with Linux.

I don't know how to do so through hostapd because the **dump_file** has been disabled so I can't even check the file for information.

Using **iw** I get:

```
~$: iw dev wlan0 station dump 
Station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (on wlan0)
    inactive time:  4190 ms
    rx bytes:   1380
    rx packets: 4
    tx bytes:   358
    tx packets: 2
    tx retries: 0
    tx failed:  0
    signal:     0 dBm
    signal avg: -26 dBm
    tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s
    rx bitrate: 36.0 MBit/s
    authorized: yes
    authenticated:  yes
    preamble:   short
    WMM/WME:    no
    MFP:        no
    TDLS peer:  no
```

But I always get **signal 0 dBm**. Does not matter the distance/location of computer connected to the AP station.

Is there an alternative solution to get signal quality or signal strength ?

Comment: Hmmm, on wr841n I just got `signal: -58 dBm`. Maybe driver issue?